# clipboard.js ios12 UIWebView Can not copy

Tags: javascript

UIWebView app cannot be replicated on iPhone phones with IOS version 12.0 or more, but it can be used normally in browsers

navigator.clipboard is undefined

```
    const clipboard = new ClipboardJS('.vaCodeCopy')
    clipboard.on('success', () => {
      toast.show(text('topup.code.copied'))
    })
    clipboard.on('error', () => {
      toast.show('error')
    })
```

Answer (score 0):

Text input will be look like:

```
<input style="width: 100%; border: none;" type="text" id="foo" value="Code to copy" />
```

Button which call the copy to clipboard function is as below:

```
<button id="copy_to_clipboard" onclick="copy('foo')" class="share-btn">Copy To Clipboard</button>
```

copy function will look like:

```
    var copy = function(elementId) {

    var input = document.getElementById(elementId);
    var isiOSDevice = navigator.userAgent.match(/ipad|iphone/i);

    if (isiOSDevice) {

        var editable = input.contentEditable;
        var readOnly = input.readOnly;

        input.contentEditable = true;
        input.readOnly = false;

        var range = document.createRange();
        range.selectNodeContents(input);

        var selection = window.getSelection();
        selection.removeAllRanges();
        selection.addRange(range);

        input.setSelectionRange(0, 999999);
        input.contentEditable = editable;
        input.readOnly = readOnly;

    } else {
        input.select();
    }

    document.execCommand('copy');
```

}

Comment: This approach was used before, but cannot be replicated in IOS 12 UI WebView app